# Firebase Web Authentication - Administrator Approval for New Accounts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've got the [Firebase Web Authentication pretty much setup and working](https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-auth) for oAuth as well as local username/pwds (email addresses).

My question is: Does anyone have an idea as to how to introduce an additional step in there such that new accounts must be approved by a site administrator prior to being fully validated?  I was thinking of tweaking/utilizing the `user.emailVerified` property but I'm thinking that won't work for oAuth users.

Is there an easy way to do this - to add an admin approval step?  Or, is there a property in the Firebase Authentication subsystem that I could easily toggle?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a user via Firebase Authentication only provides them with a unique user id. This doesn't allow them any access to your apps or "register" them in any way. That's entirely your purview. It's nothing more than a map of unique credentials (e.g. Facebook IDs or email/password hashes) to unique Firebase IDs.

You can "register" users by having any access privileges you want, and any workflow to get the user added into your Database (or any other appropriate mechanism).

Assuming database, you would write the user profile/meta data into a path, such as `/users/$uid`, and base your security rules on whether `/users/<user id>` exists.

To enforce admin approval, the simplest answer would be to maintain a separate path, such as `/registered/<user id>/true` that's only accessible by admins (and of course by security rules).

Now you can write rules like the following:

```
{
  "...some path...": {
     ".read": "root.child("registered/" + auth.uid).val() === true"
  }
}
```

Essentially enforcing a registration process.

Comment: That makes sense.  So this will enable me to add the "authorization" functionality I'm looking for.  Thanks very much.

Comment: OK, but on `auth.onAuthStateChanged` how do I determine the logged in user is registered/authorized or not?  In other words, I want to display a link/button only to registered/authorized users.  I'm thinking simply do `db.ref('/registered/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snap) { if(snap.val()===true){ //logged in user is authorized}});` is this safe?  Is this the way to do that?

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of the database.  "Dealers" = "Registered" users in your answer, i.e. same idea.  Thanks very much for your help.